# How to remove an object from a photo in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I'm new with GIMP (2.10.8). I have this photo:

[image: my image]

In this image you can see my finger and I tried to remove it with Layer > Transparency > Add Alpha Channel, I get this result...

[image: layer working]

I then tried to fill the area with the same colour surrounding it, but every time the Color Picker Tool gives me different brown shades, not the exact colour...

[image: the outcome image]

How do I properly fill this area?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What are you actually trying to achieve here? Please show the original image, and say what you want to do. Are you trying to fill the selection? Adding an alpha channel to a layer will not fill in a selection.

Comment: very thanks for your answer!, i update my question...

Comment: You are trying a very advanced stunt: showing in a photo what you camera never got to see (because what you want was under your finger). Zoom into your photo a lot and realize that such a huge area is never "just one colour". You need to learn about the cloning tools in GIMP, but that is beyond one question, you need to learn the basic use of the tools and practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different method instead. Use the Clone Tool.

1. Select the Clone Tool, choose a small soft edged brush
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to select the clone source from a different part of the bag
3. Carefully paint over a small part of the finger
4. repeat steps 2 and 3 until you have finished

Example

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!, it is what I to want.., I wish your a nice Day!